# If I add couple of words between tags, I can made up the titles! (How to call these tags?)

Tags: discussion, tags

Note: the following is based in actual facts, none of the following is a fictional work.

---

I'm not sure about these tags, reading something like this:

> How do I [del](/questions/tagged/del) [elements](/questions/tagged/elements) in a [python](/questions/tagged/python) [array](/questions/tagged/array)?

But that's not the scariest, read this one:

> [detect](/questions/tagged/detect) [capslock](/questions/tagged/capslock) and [numlock](/questions/tagged/numlock) [keyboard](/questions/tagged/keyboard) [buttons](/questions/tagged/buttons) using [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript).
>
> [detect](/questions/tagged/detect) [capslock](/questions/tagged/capslock) and [numlock](/questions/tagged/numlock) [keyboard](/questions/tagged/keyboard) [buttons](/questions/tagged/buttons) using [c](/questions/tagged/c).

Dunno, but I was under the impression that tags should have a well defined meaning and usage (most of these tags has no excerpt or an well defined topic). I get scared when something like this is possible.

How are these tags called? Ambiguous? Are they really good tags? Should be Trogdor fed with these kind of tags (excluding C, Python, and JS tags)?

Comment: We need a mass burniate list...

Comment: @Braiam there can't be such a "rule". Tag can be valid or invalid, it's specific to each tag and can't be predicted. I agree tags like [tag:detect] are invalid, the OP of the dupe already added it to his list though.

Comment: OK, think I figured what you're getting at. Not a dupe indeed, will retract my vote and hope to come with answer soon.

Comment: This is not a dupe, we shouldn't dump all burninate requests on one specific request post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those are just bad/invalid tags, no special name for them.

Most were created long time ago when creating tags required much less reputation than it does now, and people just used each word in the title as a tag. [This first revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/208436/1) of the first question in [detect](/questions/tagged/detect) tag is a good example.

We can't have any rule "what is a valid tag" or have a white list of tag names. Each tag is on its own, after being created we should consider if it's not a proper tag then act upon it.

There is already a [recent discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/213446/152859) with growing list of such tags.

Comment: Ok, finally what I wanted.

Comment: @Braiam yeah looks like you tried to insert meta humor into something that can't really have humor (tags) so it was hard to understand what you mean in there.

Comment: Meh, changed the title, maybe now is clear...